# Twitter Jquery Widget: Creating invalid URLS

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have a twitter widget on my website. The only problem is, it is creating invalid URLS for the link when you click on the "about 5 hours ago.."

Example: If you click on a recent tweet it takes you to this link, which is invalid: http://twitter.com/#!/ohshititsjake/statuses/63741419709411330

The correct url is:
http://twitter.com/#!/ohshititsjake/statuses/63741419709411328

Here is the part of the script I believe is the problem:

```
` function build_url() {
      var proto = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:');
      if (s.list) {
        return proto+"//api.twitter.com/1/"+s.username[0]+"/lists/"+s.list+"/statuses.json?per_page="+s.count+"&callback=? ";
      } else if (s.query == null && s.username.length == 1) {
        return proto+'//api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+s.username[0]+'&count='+s.count+'&callback=?';
      } else {
        var query = (s.query || 'from:'+s.username.join(' OR from:'));
        return proto+'//search.twitter.com/search.json?&q='+escape(query)+'&rpp='+s.count+'&callback=?';
      }
    }
`
```

Here is the full javascript:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.tweet = function(o){
    var s = {
      username: ["ohshititsjake"],            
      list: null,                              
      avatar_size: 20,                      
      count: 3,                               
      intro_text: null,                       
      outro_text: null,                       
      join_text:  null,                       
      auto_join_text_default: "I said:<br/>",      
      auto_join_text_ed: "I",                 
      auto_join_text_ing: "I said:<br/>",             
      auto_join_text_reply: "I replied to",   
      auto_join_text_url: "I was looking at", 
      loading_text: null,                     
      query: null                             
    };

    if(o) $.extend(s, o);

    $.fn.extend({
      linkUrl: function() {
        var returning = [];
        var regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi;
        this.each(function() {
          returning.push(this.replace(regexp,"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>"));
        });
        return $(returning);
      },
      linkUser: function() {
        var returning = [];
        var regexp = /[\@]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/gi;
        this.each(function() {
          returning.push(this.replace(regexp,"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>"));
        });
        return $(returning);
      },
      linkHash: function() {
        var returning = [];
        var regexp = /(?:^| )[\#]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/gi;
        this.each(function() {
          returning.push(this.replace(regexp, ' <a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=&tag=$1&lang=all&from='+s.username.join("%2BOR%2B")+'">#$1</a>'));
        });
        return $(returning);
      },
      capAwesome: function() {
        var returning = [];
        this.each(function() {
          returning.push(this.replace(/\b(awesome)\b/gi, '<span class="awesome">$1</span>'));
        });
        return $(returning);
      },
      capEpic: function() {
        var returning = [];
        this.each(function() {
          returning.push(this.replace(/\b(epic)\b/gi, '<span class="epic">$1</span>'));
        });
        return $(returning);
      },
      makeHeart: function() {
        var returning = [];
        this.each(function() {
          returning.push(this.replace(/(&lt;)+[3]/gi, "<tt class='heart'>&#x2665;</tt>"));
        });
        return $(returning);
      }
    });

    function parse_date(date_str) {
      // The non-search twitter APIs return inconsistently-formatted dates, which Date.parse
      // cannot handle in IE. We therefore perform the following transformation:
      // "Wed Apr 29 08:53:31 +0000 2009" => "Wed, Apr 29 2009 08:53:31 +0000"
      return Date.parse(date_str.replace(/^([a-z]{3})( [a-z]{3} \d\d?)(.*)( \d{4})$/i, '$1,$2$4$3'));
    }

    function relative_time(time_value) {
      var parsed_date = parse_date(time_value);
      var relative_to = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : new Date();
      var delta = parseInt((relative_to.getTime() - parsed_date) / 1000);
      var pluralize = function (singular, n) {
        return '' + n + ' ' + singular + (n == 1 ? '' : 's');
      };
      if(delta < 60) {
      return 'less than a minute ago';
      } else if(delta < (60*60)) {
      return 'about ' + pluralize("minute", parseInt(delta / 60)) + ' ago';
      } else if(delta < (24*60*60)) {
      return 'about ' + pluralize("hour", parseInt(delta / 3600)) + ' ago';
      } else {
      return 'about ' + pluralize("day", parseInt(delta / 86400)) + ' ago';
      }
    }

    function build_url() {
      var proto = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:' : 'http:');
      if (s.list) {
        return proto+"//api.twitter.com/1/"+s.username[0]+"/lists/"+s.list+"/statuses.json?per_page="+s.count+"&callback=? ";
      } else if (s.query == null && s.username.length == 1) {
        return proto+'//api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+s.username[0]+'&count='+s.count+'&callback=?';
      } else {
        var query = (s.query || 'from:'+s.username.join(' OR from:'));
        return proto+'//search.twitter.com/search.json?&q='+escape(query)+'&rpp='+s.count+'&callback=?';
      }
    }

    return this.each(function(i, widget){
      var list = $('<ul class="tweet_list">').appendTo(widget);
      var intro = '<p class="tweet_intro">'+s.intro_text+'</p>';
      var outro = '<p class="tweet_outro">'+s.outro_text+'</p>';
      var loading = $('<p class="loading">'+s.loading_text+'</p>');

      if(typeof(s.username) == "string"){
        s.username = [s.username];
      }

      if (s.loading_text) $(widget).append(loading);
      $.getJSON(build_url(), function(data){
        if (s.loading_text) loading.remove();
        if (s.intro_text) list.before(intro);
        var tweets = (data.results || data);
        $.each(tweets, function(i,item){
          // auto join text based on verb tense and content
          if (s.join_text == "auto") {
            if (item.text.match(/^(@([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)) .*/i)) {
              var join_text = s.auto_join_text_reply;
            } else if (item.text.match(/(^\w+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&\?\/.=]+) .*/i)) {
              var join_text = s.auto_join_text_url;
            } else if (item.text.match(/^((\w+ed)|just) .*/im)) {
              var join_text = s.auto_join_text_ed;
            } else if (item.text.match(/^(\w*ing) .*/i)) {
              var join_text = s.auto_join_text_ing;
            } else {
              var join_text = s.auto_join_text_default;
            }
          } else {
            var join_text = s.join_text;
          };

          var from_user = item.from_user || item.user.screen_name;
          var profile_image_url = item.profile_image_url || item.user.profile_image_url;
          var join_template = '<span class="tweet_join"> '+join_text+' </span>';
          var join = ((s.join_text) ? join_template : ' ');
          var avatar_template = '<a class="tweet_avatar" href="http://twitter.com/'+from_user+'"><img src="'+profile_image_url+'" height="'+s.avatar_size+'" width="'+s.avatar_size+'" alt="'+from_user+'\'s avatar" title="'+from_user+'\'s avatar" border="0"/></a>';
          var avatar = (s.avatar_size ? avatar_template : '');
          var date = '<span class="tweet_time"><a href="http://twitter.com/'+from_user+'/statuses/'+item.id+'" title="view tweet on twitter">'+relative_time(item.created_at)+'</a></span>';
          var text = '<span class="tweet_text">' +$([item.text]).linkUrl().linkUser().linkHash().makeHeart().capAwesome().capEpic()[0]+ '</span>';

          // until we create a template option, arrange the items below to alter a tweet's display.
          list.append('<li>' + avatar + date + join + text + '</li>');

          list.children('li:first').addClass('tweet_first');
          list.children('li:odd').addClass('tweet_even');
          list.children('li:even').addClass('tweet_odd');
        });
        if (s.outro_text) list.after(outro);
        $(widget).trigger("loaded").trigger((tweets.length == 0 ? "empty" : "full"));
      });

    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your "it should be this link" in the question appears to be identical to the one you describe as invalid just prior, and both appear to be invalid when you click on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the permalink's IDs on that user account, they don't match with the IDs getting generated in your post. The answer is probably in this post:

[Why a wrong tweet id is returned from twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841721/why-a-wrong-tweet-id-is-returned-from-twitter-api)

so try changing this line:

```
var date = '<span class="tweet_time"><a href="http://twitter.com/'+from_user+'/statuses/'+item.id+'" title="view tweet on twitter">'+relative_time(item.created_at)+'</a></span>';
```

to this:

```
var date = '<span class="tweet_time"><a href="http://twitter.com/'+from_user+'/statuses/'+item.id_str+'" title="view tweet on twitter">'+relative_time(item.created_at)+'</a></span>';
```

Really, it's just changing item.id to item.id_str.in the middle of that line.

Comment: Hey,Im sorry but Im new to the twitter API thing. Could you be more specific? </noob>

Comment: Aha, HERE'S the canonical explanation/reason for this: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/6a16efa375532182